# Gmail API Oauth Approval been waiting almost 3 months

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, google-oauth

I have an application which has the ability to link to a Gmail account via OAuth for a client and send email from the system.  I have created the OAuth authorization with Google almost 3 months ago. I received 2 emails from them over that time 1 was resolved within an hour the other was requesting a video which was already included in the original request.

Is google always this slow?  I have called cloud support and did not receive any help.  Anyone else had to wait months to get OAuth authorization from google?

Facebook and Microsoft were within a day.

Tried calling them cloud support (no help).  Send them feedback on the OAuth console page.  No reply.   Replied to the email they sent a request for more information on but that was over 6 weeks ago no reply.   I am trying to get access to send an email.  This has to be one of the most common use cases with Gmail.   Does not make sense that it is taking so long.

N/A.   It is a web application using Gmail oauth2

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming per se but depends on third party corporate policy and workflow on application/request approval.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with oauth from the last 2 months. Now in the JS I have removed the "scope" part and its working like a charm now.
//  'scope': 'profile email',

Answer (score 0):

The first few communications with google regarding verification went relatively quickly with 1-5 day response times. These were the "obvious error" ones. Once we resolved those, we received this on Mar 29:

> Thank you for submitting an OAuth App Verification request. We
>   appreciate your patience during this review period.
>
> The app verification process can take several weeks to complete.
>   Google will not take action against apps for non-compliance with the
>   new policy during the verification process if you are acting in good
>   faith to come into compliance. User access to your app for existing
>   approved scopes will not be impacted. All apps that have applied are
>   expected to fully complete the app verification process by May 15,
>   2019, with the remainder of 2019 to complete the security assessment.

So that is a suggested 6 week timeframe.

Have you received a similar email?

Also note: If your app is not currently available for public use ( or in development ), you can request to skip the verification process.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#skip

> This has to be one of the most common use cases with Gmail. Does not
>   make sense that it is taking so long.

It might make sense in the context of the 2019 *Restricted Scope* security requirements and the level of chaos that is creating for developers, and therefor their support/verification team.

Comment: It is a public application.  I quickly hit the limit I think about 100 clients before you have to have approval completed (Unverified app user cap).  Most of the communication with the oauth team is asking for things that i have already supplied like send a you tube video.  That was on my original submission.  I did send feedback to oauth-feedback@google.com did not hear back.   I will keep waiting.  Frustrating that they don't have an expedited approval process.  Would be ok spend a few hundred dollars to get this resolved.  I did get the 6 week email obviously that was not accurate.

Comment: The only thing I could suggest is tagging this post with 
google-oauth and google-oauth2 since those are supposed to be monitored by google support staff. I don't understand the lack of communication or support from Google.

Comment: Please follow up with oauth-feedback@google.com again. The review team is busy reviewing a large number of submissions. They will respond to your email and can get you an answer on the status of your application.

Comment: I added the other tags to the post.  Will try to email them again. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#verification-requirements), if your project contains multiple OAuth clients, Google needs videos demonstrating usage of restricted scopes for each of those clients. Failure to do so might be resulting in multiple communications. Removing unused clients from your project may help.

Answer (score -1):

Email oauth-feedback@google.com and ask them for an update on your verification status.

Comment: After 4 weeks I got another reply from them.  Asking for a user and password to test the app.  I had provided that over 30 days ago.   Not sure why they are so disorganized.  Will take another month for them to send the next reply probably ask for something that was already provided.  They did this to me regarding the video demo.  I included it in the original request.  Then they asked for it again adding another month to my wait time.

Comment: Just to close the thread.   Took almost 6 months.  Finally got them to approve it.  Then afterwards got an email that because it is a server side application I would be required to pay for an independent code audit that cost between 15k-75k. Would have been nice if google mentioned that before I wasted 6 Months on it, . 
 Not willing to drop 75k on it.  Kind of think it is unreasonable to do that to small businesses.  Really lost respect for google.